# How to access the right json value that is located through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, scripting, cypress

I'm currently using the fixture file to make sure it will be easier to call the right value.

```
 cy.fixture('latestLead.json').then(function (lead) {
            this.lead = lead
        })
My son file is the following:

{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Lead",
          "url": "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Lead/111111111"
        },
        "Id": "111111111",
        "Name": "Andres Latest Test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The way that I'm trying to get the right value is the following:

```
cy.get(".gLFyf").type(this.lead.result.records.Id)
```

I'm able to get totalSize or done from the result object, but I'm not able to get any other value higher than that object. How can I get the Id value from the records Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an array item (in your case it's the object) using the index position (in your case it's zero)

```
cy.get(".gLFyf").type(this.lead.result.records[0].Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
cy.get(".gLFyf").type(this.lead.result.records[0].Id)